# Something caught my eye

Tags: word-usage, idioms

A student asked me tonight why we say "something caught my eye," and not "something caught my eyes."  This is not just limited to eyes but also:

"lend me your ear." "Can I give you a hand?" or "an eye for detail."

Is this because we are not thinking of the actual body part but it's function?

This question was asked before but the answer and comments do not address the question very well.  [Why does “something catch my eye” but not “both my eyes”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/267910/129806)

Comment: Could you give a link to the previous question so that we can see what answers have already been given?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK take a look...not very satisfying...imho.

Comment: I've added an answer to the previous question in case this one gets closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK ok, I'll take a look.  On another note it's frustrating that questions get closed as duplicates just because they have the same keywords...I had this happen in the physics department.

Comment: @michael_timofeev - But this is a duplicate.  The fact that the previous question did not garner a very good answer doesn't change that.

Comment: Saddens me to say but Hot Licks is right. Consider also the fact that the question is only a couple of months older than yours, the same users who "didn't answer satisfactorily" are the same today. You should place a bounty on it, specifying what type of answer you're looking for.

Comment: Also try looking at questions which are highly upvoted, how they are presented. Your questions look like single-word-requests, when in actual fact they're not. You have to show some research yourself. Did you look up the idiom in a dictionary? Did you look up the expressions you have mentioned, did you ask Google about *synecdoche*, as suggested by one of the answers in the older question. Why are you not happy with this explanation? If you do these things the question stands a better chance of staying open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In dictionary, **eye** is not only defined as the organ of sight, but also as :

- sight; vision (*a sharp eye*).
- the power of seeing; appreciative or discriminating visual perception (*the eye of an artist*).
- a look, glance, or gaze (*to cast one's eye at a beautiful necklace*).

In the above meanings, "eye" is singular.

Same for **ear**:

- the sense of hearing  (*sounds that are pleasing to the ear*).
- keen or sensitive perception of the differences of sound, especially sensitiveness to the quality and correctness of musical sounds (*an ear for music; a violinist with a good ear*).
- attention; heed (*to gain a person's ear*)